# Can´t print a String from a structure in C

Tags: c, string, struct, printing, strcpy

```
typedef struct listaDocente nodoDocente;
struct listaDocente{            //teacherList
    char Rut[12];               //ID
    char Nombre[50];            //Name
    char Correo[70];            //Email
    char Cod_Curso[6];          //Grade_Code
    char Asignatura[15];        //Grade_Name
    nodoDocente *siguiente;     //Next (Node)
};

int main(){
    nodoDocente *D = ((nodoDocente * )malloc(sizeof(nodoDocente)));
    strcpy(D->Nombre, "Charlie");
    strcpy(D->Rut, "18123456");
    strcpy(D->Asignatura, "EDD");
    strcpy(D->Cod_Curso, "INS123");
    strcpy(D->Correo, "charlie@test.com");
    printf("%s\n", D->Nombre);
    printf("%s\n", D->Rut);
    printf("%s\n", D->Asignatura);
    printf("%s\n", D->Cod_Curso);
    printf("%s\n", D->Correo);

    return 0;
}
```

First, sorry if some words are in spanish.
Im trying to print these values but i'm gettin a blank space.

```
Charlie
18123456

INS123
charlie@test.com
```

Where it should be printing out EDD, like this.

```
Charlie
18123456
EDD
INS123
charlie@test.com
```

Comment: `strcpy(D->Cod_Curso, "INS123");` - may want to count how many `char` that *really* occupies (hint: don't forget the extra char for the nulchar terminator). Your code invokes *undefined behavior* with that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared :

```
char Cod_Curso[6];
```

and filled it with :

```
strcpy(D->Cod_Curso, "INS123");
```

But `INS123` is followed by the terminating character for strings `\0`. So instead of `6` characters as you might think, the string `INS123` actually occupies `7` characters. As a result, you cannot expect the statement :

```
printf("%s\n", D->Asignatura);
```

to work properly as you invoke [undefined-behavior](/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) with the previous line.

**Solution** : Declare `Cod_Curso` with size `7` (or more), like this :

```
char Cod_Curso[7];
```

---

Also, take a look at this [link on why not to cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 4):

You have copied `INS123` into `Cod_Curso[6]` using `strcpy`. Now `strcpy` reads from src until it sees a '\0' and copies what was read(including '\0') into `dest`. Hence here 7 characters will be copied to the buffer pointed by `Cod_Curso`.

Now here is the problem. The allocated space in destination buffer is only of 6 characters. Hence copying 7 characters into it will cause a buffer overflow i.e. the extra characters will be copied into memory not belonging to `Cod_Curso` but to the variable above it in the stack which here is `Asignatura[15]`. So now the extra character '\0' is copied in `Asignatura[0]`.

Now `printf` with `'%s'` prints until it sees a `'\0'` in the passed buffer. Since `Asignatura[0]` is `'\0'`, Hence an empty string is printed.

**Solution**

It is better to use safe version of `strcpy` like [strncpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncpy.htm). Or you can increase the buffer size.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that a string in C always has a trailing `\0` char. So your:

```
INS123
```

Is written

```
INS123\0
```

It's 7 char length not 6. So what you are doing is writing an additional `\0` on the first char of `Asignatura` and thus its length become 0.

To fix this issue you should declare `Cod_Curso` bi enough:

```
char Cod_Curso[7];          //Grade_Code
```

Answer (score 3):

A string needs one extra byte to store `\0` which makes an array of chars to be treated as string. You are violating this rule here,

```
char Cod_Curso[6];
strcpy(D->Cod_Curso, "INS123");
```

This overwrites `\0` to memory assigned to someother variable and that causes a [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

If you are sure about the length of each string, you can use an exactly defined lengths for your char arrays or else you can declare all of them to be `char*` and malloc each of them to store the strings you are giving or else provide sufficient array length (`buffer`) for all.

Also, there is a memory leak in your code. You should be `free`ing the memory allocated by using `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`.

`malloc` returns `void*` which is implicitly promoted to any other pointer type in C, so you don't need to cast your `malloc`.